# Runtime Cursor error in android

Tags: android, cursor

getting cursor error.i'm newbie to android so need a help.cursor shows runtime exception of CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException of Index 5 requested, with a size of 5.
In this below program i have implemented AndroidSlidingUpPanel-Master. the cursor value shows properly but when i try to scroll up the slider then throws cursor error.

```
Context mContext;
  Cursor mCursor;
  boolean movetonext = false;
  private LayoutInflater inflater;

  DownloadedFileListAdapter(Context m, Cursor c) {
      mContext = m;
      mCursor = c;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
      return mCursor.getCount();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
      return mCursor.moveToNext();
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
      return 0;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      if (inflater == null)
          inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                  .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
      if (convertView == null)
          convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_file_list, null);

      TextView fileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_file_name);
      TextView fileCreatedOn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_path_created_on);

      fileName.setText("" + mCursor.getString(0));
      fileCreatedOn.setText("" + mCursor.getString(2));

      getItem(position);

      return convertView;
  }
```

P.S :

```
10-01 12:17:26.268: E/AndroidRuntime(22538): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 requested, with a size of 5
10-01 12:17:26.268: E/AndroidRuntime(22538):    at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
10-01 12:17:26.268: E/AndroidRuntime(22538):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
10-01 12:17:26.268: E/AndroidRuntime(22538):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
10-01 12:17:26.268: E/AndroidRuntime(22538):    at com.example.socialapp.DownloadedFileListAdapter.getView(DownloadedFileListAdapter.java:56)
```

Comment: In your `getItemId` method besides returning 0 return `position`.

Comment: are you aware of [Simple]CursorAdapter ?

Comment: @GrlsHu its still showing same issue

Comment: @user3721186 use SimpleCursorAdapter, not any custom BaseAdapter/ArrayAdapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
  return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (inflater == null) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }else{
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_file_list, null);
        }else{

        TextView fileName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.downloaded_file_name);
        TextView fileCreatedOn = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.file_path_created_on);

        fileName.setText("" + mCursor.getString(0));
        fileCreatedOn.setText("" + mCursor.getString(2));

        getItem(position);
        }
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: 10-01 13:12:22.907: E/AndroidRuntime(31951):FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-01 13:12:22.907: E/AndroidRuntime(31951): Process: com.sothree.slidinguppanel.demo, PID: 31951
10-01 13:12:22.907: E/AndroidRuntime(31951): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-01 13:12:22.907: E/AndroidRuntime(31951):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2277)
10-01 13:12:22.907: E/AndroidRuntime(31951):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
10-01 13:12:22.907: E/AndroidRuntime(31951):  at com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout.onLayout(SlidingUpPanelLayout.java:698)

Comment: @user3721186 use SimpleCursorAdapter, not any custom BaseAdapter/ArrayAdapter